# cakephp: access hidden field value set in ctp, in controller without form post

Tags: javascript, session, cakephp

I am working in cakephp and javascript. Following is the scenario:
on map icon click, a jquery finction is called which displays the google map. Now through javascript, the user can drag n change the current marker position in google map. The values are set in view also. But how do i access these values(latitude, longitude) in controller?
I wish to set the latitude and longitude in session variable but i cant do that i mean icant set session variable in javascript n use it in controller.
Following is my code:

```
    function initialize() {

  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom:8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  // Update current position info.
  //alert(" initilize"); 
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    //updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
   // alert("dragStart"+marker.getPosition()); // access this value in controller
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
   // updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
    alert(marker.getPosition()); // access this value in controller
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
   // updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
    alert(marker.getPosition()); // access this value in controller
  });
}
```

in controller:

```
 public function map()
    {
         //access lat, long here

    }
```

how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting JavaScript with PHP can be done with AJAX technique.

Like this, your JavaScript code will call a concrete action in a controller and once in there, you can save it in sessions or do whatever you want to do with it.

You can call the action every X seconds or on any change, it depends on when you want to call it and the possible events you can catch from the user.

This is an example of what i mean:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //calling the function every 30 seconds
    setInterval(function(){
        getUserSavings();
        }, 30*1000);
});

function getUserSavings(){
    $.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/users/getSavings.json",
        function(dat){  
            //do whatever you want with the resulting data (dat)
            $('#totalSavings span').html(dat['result']['savings']);
    });
}
```

It is not needed to use the extension `json` but it enables you to call the action without having to define a view. For more info you can take a look at [the documentation.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)